# If $g$ is the primitive of the function $f$ such that $f(x):=(x^4+1)/(x^6+1)$ then find the family of curves represented by $g(x)$:

Tags: calculus, integration

This problem according to my level of understanding is basically finding the integration of $f$.  But how do we do it. No plan works out here. Is this fuction

$$f(x):=\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}$$

non integrable?

Comment: It is possible to do this by splitting it into partial fractions

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i solved it..

Comment: but í don't know how to write it in math jax formatting